# Am I missing something about LSTM?

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm

I have imbalanced data that I pass through a LSTM network.

Here is part of my code :

```
weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',np.unique(trainY),trainY)

print (weights)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(look_back, trainX.shape[2]), recurrent_dropout=0.3, return_sequences=True)) #
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(32,  recurrent_dropout=0.3))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print (model.summary())
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(validX, validY), epochs=100, batch_size=16, class_weight=weights, verbose=1 , callbacks=callbacks_list, shuffle=True)
```

Weights are `[0.6147541  2.67857143]` seeing good imbalance.

However, when I print confusion matrices (for each set), I only get `0`predicted.

How my data are shaped. Actually, each 2-D sequence in input of a LSTM is of size `(time_step, features)` right ? Here I use `time_step` of 1 (and `features`=22 , don't matter). So that means that's the same as if I took each sample of my time serie one-by-one.

When I increase `time_step`to something like 5, it works slightly better but I still get a too high number of "false 0" (0 is the biggest represented class) though a few-layers-MLP works very well on the same data with `class_weight` parameter. Am I doing something wrong with LSTM ?

Here is how the sequences are built: `look_back` is the size of the sliding window of instants centered around the current time step that I take and the windows overlap :

```
def create_dataset(feat,targ, look_back=2):
    semi_window=math.floor(look_back/2)
    dataX, dataY = [], []

    for i in range(semi_window,len(targ)-semi_window):
        a = feat[i-semi_window:(i+semi_window+1), :]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(targ[i])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
```

I am really waiting for help because it seems to give performances under simple MLP for example, while it's made to learn temporal dependencies on time series...